# Nodemailer Sending messages from my account to it self

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemailer

I set up nodemailer locally to send mails from my site its suppose to collect the email from the html and forward it to my gmail account through a contact form

```
<form action="http://localhost:3000/contactForm" class="form-horizontal"
method="post" role="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name"
            type="text"><br>
            <input class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email"
            type="email"><br>
            <input class="form-control" name="subject" placeholder=
            "Subject" type="text">
        </div>
    </div><br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <textarea class="form-control" cols="10" name="text"
            placeholder="Feel free to send me a mail" rows="6"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div><button id="send" value="submit">Send</button><br>
</form>
```

This is the server.js file. Everything is working as it should, the mails are being sent, the subject and text are being collected from the html passed to the server and sent to my gmail account, but the email doesn't it keeps pulling my gmail account for some reason so it's basically reading from j*********@gmail.com to j*********@gmail.com in my email account which defeats the whole point because i want the user to be able to communicate with me.

```
app.post('/contactForm', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
response = {
    email:req.body.email,
    subject:req.body.subject,
    text:req.body.text
};

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        xoauth2: xoauth2.createXOAuth2Generator({
                user: 'j********@gmail.com',
                clientId: '********************************************',
                clientSecret: '****************************************',
                refreshToken: '****************************************',
                accessToken: '*******************************************'
            })
        }   
});

var mailOptions = { 
    from: req.body.email,
    to: 'joelebuka@gmail.com',
    subject: req.body.subject,
    text: req.body.text
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) { 
    if(error) {
        return console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response)
    }
});
```

})

Thanks for reading through patiently and for any help that can be provided

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to actually send the email from the user's account with your current setup.  What you could do instead is set the `replyTo` value on the options object to the email address of the form submitter.

See the options here:

https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer#e-mail-message-fields

You can also set the `name` property.  See address formatting options here:

https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer#address-formatting